# Можно ли в react использовать дефис в className?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Например так:

```
<div className="place__list--more">
```

Где-то, не помню точно, читал, что использование дефисов может привести к ошибкам.

Comment: В чём проблема попробовать самому? (:

Comment: Ни в чем, просто поставил дефис, но всё норм отображается

Comment: Наверное вы это читали про БЭМ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так-то можно.

Если вы используете [CSS-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules), то просто придётся заворачивать в скобки:

```
import s from './my_styles.scss';

render() {
    return (
        <div className={s['place__list-more']}> </div>
    );
}
```

[Источник](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules#naming)

Если вы используете классический подход, то никаких проблем не возникнет, если название класса является валидной строкой:

```
import './my_styles.scss';

render() {
    return (
        <div className={'place__list-more'}> </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Ого, впервые вижу подобный подход с импортированием SCSS файла и обращением с ним как с JS объектом. Буду очень благодарен если Вы поделитесь ссылкой или названием подхода

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach а как вы обычно в реакте используете стили? https://medium.com/@Connorelsea/using-sass-with-create-react-app-7125d6913760

Comment: У Вас написано `s['my-class']`, что как бы обращается к `s` как к объекту. Как я обычно делаю `className={"my-class"}`. По ссылке что Вы привели не понял, там нет примеров с подобным синтаксисом

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach https://glenmaddern.com/articles/css-modules